# Kanban - Simple Backlog Forecasting?

Tags: kanban, jira

Does anyone know if it's possible with Jira to cover the following scenario?

- The team estimates the items in its backlog in story points
- The backlog is prioritized
- The backlog is handled like a Fifo queue; the team works on the highest items first
- The team has a known velocity, predicted by the last days' weather method

Because every item is estimated and velocity and priority are known, I'd be able to show the estimated time when an item is finished. The calculation could be updated dynamically, for example when someone reprioritizes an item or something gets finished.

The easiest solution I can think of is to simply add another field to each item which is then shown in the Kanban view. Has anyone experience with something like this?

Comment: Disclaimer: asked here as well: https://www.reddit.com/r/jira/comments/bea9m1

Comment: This kinda sounds like you've answered your own question and are just looking for validation, which I'm not sure fits well here. With a situation like this, if it works well, then mazel tov. The only thing I could think to challenge is why use story points instead of lead time trends, but that feels nit-picking. Again, if it works for you, I think you've found a perfectly viable solution.

Comment: I can imagine this working as well, my question was more about the next step: is this possible with Jira? How would you do this then? I'm not sure if this is the right platform to ask this tutor of question... Not sure where a better place would be either.

Answer (score 1):

With Kanban, your biggest forecasting tool will be cycle time. I'd start by understanding what your team's average cycle time is (by product, version, or sprint), to help predict how many items could be processed in a specific time period. Jira tracks this using the control chart, which is one of the reports. Out of the box, this report will give you predictability visuals as well.

Comment: Cycle or lead time won’t help predict how many times can be done in a specific time period, that’s what throughput is for.

Comment: average cycle time will help forecast how long backlog items might take before they can be implemented, accounting for the difference in estimates for the items on the backlog.